# Symfony forms - image value disapiered when   isValid()  return False

Tags: forms, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Ok problem is simple. In my registration form when i press submit button and validation is not ok , symfony rerutn all values exept  image , password , repead password . How to fix this ? I want when validation is wrong , returned form to show all values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour when uploading files, if it's not persisted it's not able to show it again. In order to be able to show the image again, you must temporarily upload the file even if the form is not correct, then you can show it back again.

Password fields are not shown again because of security concerns. It's usually handled by the browser not by your symfony app.